# 2D array of strings in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm making an application in C that will use text menus. So, I decided to create a global array containing all the menus. As a workaround of an issue I will mention later, the code looks like this:

```
char* main_menu[]=
{"Refresh rate", "Help", "Default config", NULL};
char* other_stuff[]=
{"Stuff", "More", NULL};

char** screens[]={main_menu, other_stuff};
```

And I can use those strings like: `screens[0][1]` meaning first (or rather second, since we count from zero) option in zeroth/first menu.

It works, but it strikes me as quite inelegant that I had to declare those  auxilliary arrays (`main_menu` and `other_stuff`). I tried to make use of nested brace initialization of arrays, but always the compiler would complain. Also, before you suggest declaring the array as, say, `char* screeens[10][5]` - there should be no magic numbers, as this is equally inelegant for me.

I tried:

```
char** screens[]={
{"Refresh rate", "Help", "Default config", NULL},
{"Stuff", "More", NULL}
};
```

However, the compiler gives me a warning (and rightfully, as accessing elements yields gibberish):

```
../main.c:96:1: warning: braces around scalar initializer [enabled by default]
 {"Refresh rate", "Help", "Default config", NULL},
^
../main.c:96:1: warning: (near initialization for ‘screens[0]’) [enabled by default]
../main.c:96:1: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
../main.c:96:1: warning: (near initialization for ‘screens[0]’) [enabled by default]
../main.c:96:1: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
```

and so on.

If I change the first line to `char* screens[][]={`, the compiler won't compile the code at all, giving error: `error: array type has incomplete element type`.

I'm writing in embedded evironment (avr-gcc 4.8.1), where memory is quite scarce, so I don't want to declare arrays bigger than necessary, thus wasting memory. Is there anything I can do, or is this as simple as possible?

Comment: This is not a 2D array, but a 1D array of pointers to C strings (aka arrays of `char`).

Comment: The first thing I tried is mentioned at the very bottom (`char* screens[][]`), which is the reason question title mentions 2D arrays. Only because it did not work, I switched to the current version. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I just saw the code. Most people confuse this. Anyway, for a menu-structure, a list or tree would be the better approach, however.

Comment: @Olaf: I suspect that if it is menus, the request would be for an array of ragged arrays of structures, where the structures would contain more information than just the string identifying the menu option.

Comment: I think you meant to call me (@akrasuski1). And you are right, initially, those were even structures, containing menu title and options array, but since that did not work for the same reasons as described here, I decided to use arrays, as they are simpler - you can imagine my surprise when they failed as well...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I agree, but OP seems exactly to try this. If it is l10n, a 1D array would be sufficient, The same if all entries of a single menu are to be printed.

Comment: If you have more than few menues with few entries, you should stick with the struct approach. Typically a tree of linked lists is used.

Comment: If this was more complicated system, I would use what you suggest. But in my use case, there are only two level of menus: Main menu, and detailed option setting, so I think array of structs representing menus is OK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have C99 or later, you can use 'compound literals' to initialize your array:

```
#include <stddef.h>    // NULL

char **screens2[] =
{
    (char *[]){ "Refresh rate", "Help", "Default config", NULL },
    (char *[]){ "Stuff", "More", NULL },
};
```

Or, if you want to be `const`-correct (a good thing — thanks to [M.M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505939/m-m) and his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385287/2d-array-of-strings-in-c/32385633?noredirect=1#comment52643355_32385633)):

```
char const * const * screens3[] =
{
    (char const * const []){ "Refresh rate", "Help", "Default config", NULL },
    (char const * const []){ "Stuff", "More", NULL },
};
```

Compilation (clean — no warnings or errors):

```
gcc -std=c11 -O3 -g -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -c 2das.c
```

(GCC 5.1.0 on Mac OS X 10.10.5)

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. For the future readers - here is a short introduction into the topic: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Compound-Literals.html

Comment: Recommend using `char const * const *` and `(char const * const [])`

Comment: Clerical: How does one get comment link like [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385287/2d-array-of-strings-in-c/32385633?noredirect=1#comment52643355_32385633)?

Comment: @chux: The link for a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385287/2d-array-of-strings-in-c/32385633?noredirect=1#comment52643964_32385633) comes from clicking on the 'time' after a comment.  And the user link from the [user's name](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux), of course.

Comment: [Nice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385287/2d-array-of-strings-in-c/32385633?noredirect=1#comment52644042_32385633)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm making an application in C that will use text menus.

You could try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>

typedef int (*menu)(void);

void clearScreen(int x){
    int i=0;
    for(;i<x;i++){
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int exitMenu(void) {
    clearScreen(100);
    printf("Exiting... Goodbye\n");
    sleep(1);
    return 0;
}

int mainMenu(void){
    clearScreen(100);
    printf("\t\t\tMain Manu\n");
    return 0;
}

int updateSystem(void) {
    clearScreen(100);
    printf("System update...\n");
    sleep(1);
    return 1;
}

int installVlcFromPpa(void) {
    clearScreen(100);
    printf("Install VLC from PPA \n");
    sleep(1);
    return 0;
}

int installVlcFromSource(void) {
    clearScreen(100);
    printf("Install VLC from Source \n");
    sleep(1);
    return 0;
}

int uninstallVLC(void) {
    clearScreen(100);
    printf("Uninstall VLC... \n");
    sleep(1);
    return 1;
}

int chooseOption(int min, int max){
    int option,check;
    char c;

    do{
        printf("Choose an Option:\t");

        if(scanf("%d%c",&option,&c) == 0 || c != '\n'){
            while((check = getchar()) != 0 && check != '\n');
            printf("\tThe option has to be between %d and %d\n\n",min,max);
        }else if(option < min || option > max){
            printf("\tThe option has to be between %d and %d\n\n",min,max);
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }while(1);

    return option;
}

void showMenu(char *question, char **options, menu *actions, int length) {
    int choose = 0;
    int repeat = 1;
    int i;
    menu act;

    do {
        printf("\n\t %s \n", question);

        for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            printf("%d. %s\n", (i+1), options[i]);
        }

        choose = chooseOption(1,length);
        printf(" \n");

        act = actions[choose - 1];
        repeat = act();

        if(choose == 3){
            repeat = 0;
        }
    }while(repeat == 1);
}

int installVLC(void) {
    clearScreen(100);
    char *question = "Installing VLC from:";
    char *options[10] = {"PPA", "Source", "Back to VLC menu"};
    menu actions[3] = {installVlcFromPpa, installVlcFromSource, mainMenu};

    showMenu(question, options, actions, 3);
    return 1;
}

int meniuVLC(void) {
    clearScreen(100);
    char *question = "VLC Options";
    char *options[10] = {"Install VLC.", "Uninstall VLC.", "Back to Menu."};
    menu actions[3] = {installVLC, uninstallVLC, mainMenu};

    showMenu(question, options, actions, 3);

    return 1;
}

void startMenu(void){
    clearScreen(100);
    char *question = "Choose a Menu:";
    char *options[10] = {"Update system.", "Install VLC", "Quit"};
    menu actions[3] = {updateSystem, meniuVLC, exitMenu};

    showMenu(question, options, actions, 3);
}

int main(void){
    startMenu();
    return 0;
}
```

> ```
>      Choose a Menu: 
> 1. Update system.
> 2. Install VLC
> 3. Quit
> Choose an Option:
> ```

Comment: This is not compact at all. As I said, I value elegance of code, and in your sample all of the functions repeat `clearScreen(100);`, `return 0;` and the rest of boilerplate. Apart of lack of elegance, this has an impact on code size, which for me, embedded developer, is important.

Comment: @akrasuski1 That approach was to make things clear, of course your approach will look different. Try it first.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I misunderstood the code due to not reading it to the end. Now I see those first functions only represent actions to be taken in each selection.

Answer (score -2):

The most elegant way is to declare them as separate variables.
You can also use the first method but utilizing enums/defines, so that you have `screens[MAIN_MENU][...]` rather that some magic `screens[0xcafebabe][...]`, it is equally acceptable.